# Accessibility Identifier of UIBarButton Item Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, appium-ios

I am programmatically creating a UIBarButtonItem and setting its accessibility identifier and label. Here is the code I am using for it.

```
_rightBarButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
    buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bt_send_.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f)];
    [_rightBarButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_rightBarButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendQuickNote:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //Accessibility Identifier for Send Button
    _rightBarButton.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    _rightBarButton.accessibilityIdentifier = @"Send Note";
    _rightBarButton.accessibilityLabel = @"Send Note";
    [_rightBarButton setTitle:@"Send Note" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.sendButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_rightBarButton];
    self.sendButtonItem.enabled = NO;

    //Accessibility Identifier for Send Button
    self.sendButtonItem.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    self.sendButtonItem.accessibilityIdentifier = @"Send Note";
    self.sendButtonItem.accessibilityLabel = @"Send Note";
    [self.sendButtonItem setTitle:@"Send Note"];


    [self.navigationItem addRightBarButtonItem:self.sendButtonItem];
```

But the accessibility Identifiers are not available in Appium inspector. What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't say which version of iOS you're using. I've seen the same thing with iOS 9.0. (9.1 works as expected)

Comment: @Zach Did you get the reason?